# More human-readable tests messages with Erlang EUnit?

Tags: erlang, eunit

I am used to JavaScript testing, especially its BDD frameworks and libraries like [Chai](http://chaijs.com/) where I can describe tests in a human-readable manner and name tests with strings, e.g. "UserProfile -> Update First Name", then see these message as the output when running tests.

Is it possible to write Erlang tests in a more natural way, or at least, integrate descriptions in to tests run process, not just have them as comments, but see the name of a test which failed?

Answer (score 4):

Yes.  To add descriptions to tests, the tests need to be "test objects" instead of plain tests.  For example, change this test:

```
foo_test() ->
    run_foo(),
    ensure_foo_works().
```

to this:

```
foo_test_() ->
    ?_test(
      begin
        run_foo(),
        ensure_foo_works()
      end).
```

That is, the name of the function should end with `_test_`, and the body of the test should be wrapped in a `?_test` macro.  There are other such "wrapper macros" starting with an underscore; for example, a simple assertion can be rewritten like this:

```
%% before
check_foo_test() ->
    ?assertEqual(ok, foo()).

%% after
check_foo_test_() ->
    ?_assertEqual(ok, foo()).
```

Once you have a "test object", you can wrap it in a tuple, where the first element is a string:

```
foo_test_() ->
    {"Ensure that foo works",
     ?_test(
       begin
         run_foo(),
         ensure_foo_works()
       end)}.

check_foo_test_() ->
    {"Check that foo is ok", ?_assertEqual(ok, foo())}.
```

Those descriptions will be printed when the test fails.  If you run eunit in verbose mode, they will be printed when the test executes as well.